# How to get rid of the specific margin in Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, margin

I don’t know why, but a strange margin appears on a site made with Twitter Bootstrap 3.
If I erase the element which causes it, the margin disappears. But the element (an image) is correctly placed.

The element is that i have marked with the red arrow [here](http://imageshack.com/a/img802/277/8fy3.jpg) (the third image with the woman & baby).

I wrote the follow code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <div id="esc1">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" src="img/escuela-1.png"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div id="esc2">
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" src="img/escuela-2.png"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <div id="esc3">           
            <img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" src="img/escuela-3.png"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

URL of the site: [Here](http://firenetworks.eu/abc4/index.php)

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you investigated it yet? - http://prntscr.com/2ruvgl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <div id="cartel2">
                    <div class="cartel-img"><img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" src="img/cartel-centros-solo.png"> </div>
                  </div>
```

Section should be:

```
<div class="**container**">
            <div class="**row**">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                  <div id="cartel2">
                    <div class="cartel-img"><img class="img-responsive center-block" alt="" src="img/cartel-centros-solo.png"> </div>
                  </div>
```

That made the margin disappear for me.

Comment: Exactly the solution I have posted before you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your div's inside of the row with `<div class="col-xs-12"></div>`.  Right now you are telling the divs to display in a block of four with nothing for it to divide into.

Since BS3 is mobile first if you define your grid as col-xs-4 you don't need to define col-md and col-lg.  You only need to do that if you want it to display different on a larger screen.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Don´t understand...i have tried put <div class="col-xs-12"></div> into the container of these divs, but still having the same problem...

And i want to divide it in 3 colums, if not, the three images displays one per row

Answer (score 0):

your problem is on the box under the images :

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="escuela-def">
                        <p>La primera y principal razón de ABC KINDERGARTEN es el reconocimiento del niño/a como sujeto desde el momento de su nacimiento.<br>
En ésta escuela se da una educación integral, que abarca todas las áreas en las que el niño pueda ser estimulado desde pequeño, para alcanzar su máximo desarrollo en un marco bilingüe conectado con la familia.</p>
            ...

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

You need to inverse .row and .container, see code below :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        ...

       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For the "Galería de imágenes" too.